# SQL | Adding a specific amount and outputting the sum in a seperate column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to implement a SQL query where I need to add up a specific amount of employees hired per week, month, year and display that into a named column. So i.e. Total Hired Per Week, Total Hired Per Month, Total Hired for Year.

Two tables are joined. One is a simple table that lists every single day since 1-1-1900 to 12-31-2099. The other is a simple employee database that lists their Hire Date.

Adding explanations will assist me in learning SQL logic and will be a plus.

I am giving the query below and the output as well in the picture:

[image].

If I have not explained my issue clearly, please advise and I will try to restate my question.

Query:

```
DECLARE      @STARTDATE DATETIME,
             @ENDDATE DATETIME

SET          @STARTDATE = '1989-12-31' --  >=
SET          @ENDDATE = '2015-10-31 23:59:59' -- <

SELECT       c.calendarDate,
             Count(e.empid) as Number_Hired,
             datepart(week,c.calendarDate) as Week,
             datepart(month,c.calendarDate) as Month,
             datepart(year,c.calendarDate) as Year


FROM         intranet.dbo.igbl_calendar c

LEFT JOIN    intranet.dbo.iemp_employee e on CONVERT(DATE, c.calendarDate) = CONVERT(DATE, e.hireDate) and aliasID = 'P'

WHERE        c.calendarDate BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE

GROUP BY     c.calendarDate

ORDER BY     c.calendarDate
```

Comment: Hi. You haven't said what your problem is. What doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of `igbl_calendar` is, as `hireDate` looks to already be a `date` (or `datetime`) value, so you can just GROUP BY a date value straight away.

Comment: @Turophile the query given does not solve the issue, it only shows week number in a year, month number, so on... the problem was the task on the first paragraph.

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve? I get that you want "Total Hired Per Week" etc. as columns but what (if anything) as you going to have on rows/grouping? An example of the final output you are trying to achieve would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all you're looking to do is add on 3 additional columns to the current query, you could left join inline views or CTEs that do the individual counts for week, month, year.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME = '1989-12-31'
    , @ENDDATE DATETIME = '2015-10-31 23:59:59'

SELECT
     c.calendarDate,
     Count(e.empid) as Number_Hired,
     datepart(week, c.calendarDate) as [Week],
     datepart(month, c.calendarDate) as [Month],
     datepart(year, c.calendarDate) as [Year],
     ew.WeekCount Number_Hired_This_Week,
     em.MonthCount Number_Hired_This_Month,
     ey.YearCount Number_Hired_This_Year
FROM
    intranet.dbo.igbl_calendar c
    LEFT JOIN intranet.dbo.iemp_employee e on c.calendarDate = e.hireDate AND aliasID = 'P'
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATEPART(ww, hireDate) [Week]
        , DATEPART(yy, hireDate) [Year]
        , COUNT(empid) [WeekCount]
        FROM intranet.dbo.iemp_employee
        GROUP BY DATEPART(ww, hireDate), DATEPART(yy, hireDate)) ew
        ON ew.[Week] = DATEPART(ww, c.calendarDate)
        AND ew.[Year] = DATEPART(yy, c.calendarDate)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATEPART(mm, hireDate) [Month]
        , DATEPART(yy, hireDate) [Year]
        , COUNT(empid) [MonthCount]
        FROM intranet.dbo.iemp_employee
        GROUP BY DATEPART(mm, hireDate), DATEPART(yy, hireDate)) em
        ON em.[Month] = DATEPART(mm, c.calendarDate)
        AND em.[Year] = DATEPART(yy, c.calendarDate)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT  DATEPART(yy, hireDate) [Year]
        , COUNT(empid) [YearCount]
        FROM intranet.dbo.iemp_employee
        GROUP BY DATEPART(yy, hireDate)) ey
        ON ey.[Year] = DATEPART(yy, c.calendarDate)
WHERE
    c.calendarDate BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
GROUP BY
    c.calendarDate, ew.WeekCount, em.MonthCount, ey.YearCount
ORDER BY
    c.calendarDate
```

The basic logic being you want to find the total for a year by grouping them by the year (using datepart here), the total for each month by grouping them by year and month, and the total for each week by grouping on year and week. And then joining them back to the original query based on year/month/week.

Though honestly, I'd just do them in separate queries rather than having them all output in the one.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would minimize using `JOIN` when solving this kind of problem since the `KEY` that you need to `JOIN` together requires further processing, `datepart()` in this context.

I prefer to use a nested `SELECT` statement instead.

```
DECLARE      @STARTDATE DATETIME,
             @ENDDATE DATETIME

SET          @STARTDATE = '1989-12-31' --  >=
SET          @ENDDATE = '2015-10-31 23:59:59' -- <

WITH EmpData AS (
    SELECT  count(*) 'HireCount', 
            datepart(year, e.hireDate) 'HireYear',
            datepart(month, e.hireDate) 'HireMonth',
            datepart(week, e.hireDate) 'HireWeek'
    FROM    intranet.dbo.iemp_employee e
    WHERE   e.aliasID = 'P'
    GROUP BY datepart(year, e.hireDate), datepart(month, e.hireDate), datepart(week, e.hireDate)
)

SELECT
     datepart(year, c.calendarDate) AS Year,
     datepart(month, c.calendarDate) AS Month,
     datepart(week, c.calendarDate) AS Week,
     (SELECT sum(HireCount) FROM EmpData WHERE datepart(year, c.calendarDate) = HireYear) 'Year Hire Count',
     (SELECT sum(HireCount) FROM EmpData WHERE datepart(year, c.calendarDate) = HireYear AND datepart(month, c.calendarDate) = HireMonth) 'Month Hire Count',
     (SELECT sum(HireCount) FROM EmpData WHERE datepart(year, c.calendarDate) = HireYear AND datepart(month, c.calendarDate) = HireMonth AND datepart(week, c.calendarDate) = HireWeek) 'Week Hire Count'
FROM
    intranet.dbo.igbl_calendar c
WHERE
    c.calendarDate BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
GROUP BY
    datepart(year, c.calendarDate) as Year, datepart(month, c.calendarDate) as Month, datepart(week, c.calendarDate) as Week
ORDER BY
    1,2,3
```

Comment: Should the `DECLARE ...` statements put before the `WITH` in the query? It won't run

Comment: @Eric the variables need to be declared before they are *used*, but as they are not used in the WITH statement they do not have to be declared before it. Having said that it's usually good practice to put variable declarations at the beginning of a script.

Comment: @Nathan But it is illegal to put `DECLARE` right after the `WITH` statement, right? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/3562

Comment: @Eric Sorry, yes you are absolutely correct - I didn't look closely enough. The query (select) using the CTE must come directly after the CTE is defined (in the WITH statement), so in this case the variables must be declared before the WITH statement.